# Python - detect if filename containing given characters exists

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if a file exists. So I use the following code :

```
if os.path.exists(filepath + "Piezometrie.xlsx"):
    try :
       # do something
    else:
        pass
```

When I want to check if a file contains some specific characters, I use :

```
piezo = filepath + "Piezometrie.xlsx"
texte = "zom"

if re.search(texte, piezo):
    print "ok"
else:
    print "ko"
```

But how could I do to check **if a file that contains specific characters** (like "zom" in this example) exists (by using regex) ?

Thank you very much !
Julien

Comment: But he is not searching in txt, he is searching in xlsx

Comment: Use glob: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: Are you trying to check the file *name* or the file *contents*?

Comment: @A_Elric, @jpmc26: Look at the wording used by @Julien to describe the second code snippet. Apparently, the phrase "if a file contains some specific character" is meant to refer to the file name. Hence, he's asking not about the file content. If so, sokoli's answer should do. Or ``glob``, of course.

Answer (score 0):

List all files in directory and check every one for text. For example: (pseudocode)

```
files = os.get_files_in_directory('/home/user/')
files_with_sth_in_name = [filename for filename in files if re.search(texte, piezo)
```

Or use something made for such job: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: ``piezo`` should read ``filename``, and the second line needs a closing bracket.